# Filtering the data using Jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Filtering the data after checking the checkbox using Jquery and ajax
This is search.php

```
 <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">library_books</i>Courses</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal well" action="<?php echo base_url();?>search" method="post" role="form">
            <span>
            <?php foreach($coursedata as $val){
            ?>
            <p>
            <input class="with-gap filter_course CheckCourse" name="course_offrd_name[]" 
            multiple type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>" 
            value="<?php
            echo $val->course_offrd_name;?>" 
            <?php 
            if(!empty($courserecord))
               if(count($courserecord)==1)
                  if($courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name']==$val->course_offrd_name) {
            echo $courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name'];
            echo "checked";
                }
                else { 
                }?>/>
            <label for="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name?>"></label>
            </p>
            <?php } ?> 
            </span>
            <br>
            </form>
          </div>
</li>
<div class="col m9 s12" id="college_data">
     <main>
                      <!-- card open -->
                    <?php foreach ($record as $res) {?>
                      <div class="col s12 m6 l4 ">
                        <div class="card sticky-action hoverable wow bounce">
                          <div class="card-image waves-block ">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>">
                              <div class="header-container">
                                <?php if (isset($res->header_img) && !empty($res->header_img)) { ?>
                                <img class="activator" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/college_header/<?php echo $res->header_img;?>">
                                <?php } else {?>
                                  <img class="activator" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/header_img.png" alt="<?php echo $res->collg_name; ?>">
                                <?php } ?>
                              </div> 
                            </a>
                               <!-- <img class="activator" src="<?php// echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php// echo $d->header_img;?>">-->

                          </div>
                          <div class="card-content">
                            <?php if (isset($res->logo_img) && !empty($res->logo_img)) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>"><img class="colleg_logo hoverable circle" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/college_logo/<?php  echo $res->logo_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $res->collg_name; ?>"></a>
                            <?php } else {?>
                              <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>"><img class="colleg_logo hoverable circle" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/default_logo.png" alt="<?php echo $res->collg_name; ?>"></a>
                              <?php } ?>
                              <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>"<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 truncate" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $res->collg_name;?></span></a>

                            <p><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable">About-College</a>
                              <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable"> Placement</a> -->
                              <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable"> Course</a>
                              <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable"> Exam</a> -->
                              <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable">Book seat</a>
                              <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable">Gallery</a> -->

                            </p><br>
                             <p class="center-align">
                              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger hoverable " href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_request/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>">
                              <i class="material-icons left">check</i>Get Details</a>
                             <!-- <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn orange modal-trigger" href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_request"></a> -->
                            </p> <br> 
                          <p class="center-align">
                           <p class="center-align">
                              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger hoverable" href="<?php echo base_url();?>broucher_request/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>">
                              <i class="material-icons left">arrow_downward</i>Brochure</a>
                            <!--  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn orange modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>-->
                           </p> 
                          </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      <!-- card close -->

                     </div>


                      <!-- <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a> -->
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php if($this->session->userdata("user_login")){?>
                    <div class="back_button ">
                            <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>"class="btn-floating btn-large hoverable"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
                    </div>

                          <?php }  else {?>
                    <div class="back_button ">
                      <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>"class="btn-floating btn-large hoverable"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
                    </div>

                          <?php } ?>
                       <?php if($this->session->userdata("user_login")){
            //  print_r($_SESSION);die;
                ?>
              <div class="fixed-action-btn verticle ">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-large tooltipped pulse wow zoomIn" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Settings">
                  <i class="large material-icons">settings</i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>logout" class="btn-floating tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="logout"><i class="material-icons" >logout</i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>change-password/<?php echo $array['id']?>" class="btn-floating tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Change password"><i class="material-icons" >lock_open</i></a></li>
                <?php 
                  if($_SESSION['user_role']=='student'){ ?>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>student_panel/<?php echo $record1[0]->reg_id;?>" class="btn-floating"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>
               <?php   }
               elseif($_SESSION['user_role']=='superadmin'){ ?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin_panel" class="btn-floating tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Admin panel"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>
                  <?php }
                  elseif ($_SESSION['user_role']=='college') { ?>


             <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>college_panel/<?php echo $record2[0]->collg_id;?>" class="btn-floating "><i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>


               <?php   }
               elseif ($_SESSION['user_role']=='dataentry') { ?>


                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin_panel" class="btn-floating"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>


                  <?php   }
                  else{ ?>

                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="btn-floating"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>
                 <?php }
             ?>

                </ul>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
            <div class="col m9 s12" id="filter_data">

            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".filter_course").click(function(){
         // alert();
        $("#college_data").html('');
        $("#filter_data").html('');
        var check_course =[];
        $.each($('.CheckCourse:checked'), function() {
         check_course.push($(this).val()); 
         });

        alert(check_course);

        $.ajax({ 
         alert('hello');


        url:js_base_url+"home/check_course",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{check_course:check_course},  
        success: function(response){

        var len = response.length;
        //alert(len);

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var collg_name = response[i].collg_name;
        var header_img=response[i].header_img;
        //alert(header_img);

        var logo_img=response[i].logo_img;


        if(header_img!=""){
          var college_header_img='<img class="activator" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/college_header/'+header_img+'">';
        }
        else{
          var college_header_img='<img class="activator" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/header_img.png" alt="">';}
        if(logo_img!=""){
          var college_logo_img='<a href=""><img class="colleg_logo hoverable circle" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/college_logo/'+logo_img+'" alt=""></a>';
        }
        else{

           var college_logo_img='<a href=""><img class="colleg_logo hoverable circle" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/default_logo.png" alt=""></a>';
        }

        //var tr_str='<div class="col s12 m6 l4"><div class="card sticky-action hoverable wow bounce"><div class="card-content"><div class="card-image waves-block "><a href=""><div class="header-container">'+college_header_img+'</div> </a></div>'+college_logo_img+'<a href="#"'+'<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 truncate" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">'+collg_name+'</span></a>'+'<p><a href="#" class="chip hoverable">About-College</a><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable"> Course</a></p><br><br><p class="center-align"><p class="center-align"></p></p></div></div></div><div class="back_button"><a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="btn-floating btn-large hoverable "><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a></div>';
        var tr_str='<div class="col s12 m6 l4"><div class="card sticky-action hoverable wow bounce"><div class="card-content"><div class="card-image waves-block "><a href=""><div class="header-container">'+college_header_img+'</div> </a></div>'+college_logo_img+'<a href="#"'+'<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 truncate" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">'+collg_name+'</span></a>'+'<p><a href="#" class="chip hoverable">About-College</a><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_details/<?php echo $res->collg_id;?>" class="chip hoverable"> Course</a></p><br><p class="center-align"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger hoverable " href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/college_request"><i class="material-icons left">check</i>Get Details</a></p> <br><p class="center-align"><p class="center-align"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger hoverable" href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/broucher_request"><i class="material-icons left">arrow_downward</i>Brochure</a></p> </p><br><p class="center-align"><p class="center-align"></p></p></div></div></div><div class="back_button "><a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="btn-floating btn-large hoverable"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a></div>';
        $("#filter_data").append(tr_str);

        }
        }
        });

        });

        });


        </script>
```

This is controller.php

```
    function check_course(){

        $check_course = implode(' , ',$this->input->post('check_course'));

         $collegecoursedata = $this->front->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_college where course_name  in('.$check_course.')','result_array');

        $data['collegecoursedata'] = json_decode(json_encode($collegecoursedata),True);  
        echo json_encode($data['collegecoursedata']);

    }
```

This is model

```
    function query($sql,$rowResult)
        {
            return $this->db->query($sql)->$rowResult();
        }
```

Except controller and model all code(jQuery,ajax) are in same page.
I m trying to filter the data ie i have two checkbox one is Medical courses and 2nd is Engineering .if i checkbox the Medical course it should filter the name of the college ,college id ie it is like a card shape data with all details. say for eg  if medical courses is available in two college it should display two cards and same for engineering.
    here when i use alert('hello'); in $.ajax it is not giving me alert call.
    why the alert('hello') function is not called and if alert is called then whether the data is filtering or not?
how the data is filtered and my data is coming in form of json with jQuery ?
if need more code will help.
how to solve this type of issue?
 why the alert('hello') function is not called and if alert is called then whether the data is filtering or not?
how the data is filtered and my data is coming in form of json with jQuery ?

Comment: @M.Hemant Hi Hemant how r u?

Comment: M fine, Can you show us your $_POST data in the controller and your created query before executing it?

Comment: @M.Hemant This is controller code                                      $bata = array(
     'course_offrd_name' => $this->input->post('course_offrd_name')
     );
     
     echo json_encode($bata);
     
     $data = $this->front->get_data_wheree($table);

Comment: @M.Hemant This is model code function get_data_wheree($table)
{
    $this->db->select('course_offrd_name, collg_id');
    $this->db->group_by('course_offrd_name');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
   
}

Comment: my alert('hello'); is not called inside the $.ajax function

Comment: did you check your query result? I think if you checked more then one course then your query will fail Secondly did you check your console portion for js related errors?

Comment: @M.Hemant i m getting both courses medical as well as engineering with their respective id

Comment: Did you change your controller and Model code?

Comment: @M.Hemant in console portion i m getting 500 internal server error